# CSS print layout with fixed header and footer and with content that wraps from left column to right before flowing onto next page

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am trying to put together some html and css that when printing a document in Chrome:

- Display a fixed header and footer on each page
- Show 2 columns of information. Ideally these columns would flow from left to right before moving onto the next page.

I attempted to adapt [this nice guide](https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a) which uses fixed headers and footers with spacers in `thead` and `tfoot`. My snippet below which is close to what I want (click PRINT ME to see the print layout):

```css
.page-header, .page-header-space {
  height: 100px;
}

.page-footer, .page-footer-space {
  height: 100px;
}

.page-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid black; /* for demo */
}

.page-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0mm;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(22, 7, 7); /* for demo */
}

.two-column {
  column-count: 2;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0
}

table {
  width: 100%
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  break-inside: avoid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


@page {
  margin: 20mm;
  size: 'A4';
  
}

@media print {
   thead {display: table-header-group;} 
   tfoot {display: table-footer-group;}
   
   button {display: none;}
   
   body {margin: 0;}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="page-header" style="text-align: center">
    I'm The Header
    <br/>
    <button type="button" onClick="window.print()" style="background: pink">
      PRINT ME!
    </button>
</div>
<div class="page-footer">
  I'm The Footer
</div>

        <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="page-header-space"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
         </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                 <div class='two-column'>
                  <div class='content'>1</div>
                  <div class='content'>2</div>
                  <div class='content'>3</div>
                  <div class='content'>4</div>
                  <div class='content'>5</div>
                  <div class='content'>6</div>
                  <div class='content'>7</div>
                  <div class='content'>8</div>
                  <div class='content'>9</div>
                  <div class='content'>10</div>
                  <div class='content'>11</div>
                  <div class='content'>12</div>
                  <div class='content'>13</div>
                  <div class='content'>14</div>
                  <div class='content'>15</div>
                  <div class='content'>16</div>
                  <div class='content'>17</div>
                  <div class='content'>18</div>
                  <div class='content'>19</div>
                  <div class='content'>20</div>
                  <div class='content'>21</div>
                  <div class='content'>22</div>
                  <div class='content'>23</div>
                  <div class='content'>24</div>
                  <div class='content'>25</div>
                  <div class='content'>26</div>
                  <div class='content'>27</div>
                  <div class='content'>28</div>
                  <div class='content'>29</div>
                  <div class='content'>30</div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  
                 </div>
              </td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
          
          <tfoot>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <!--place holder for the fixed-position footer-->
           <div class="page-footer-space"></div>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>          
</html>
```

The problem is that when then first column breaks in the print preview there is an additional 100px of space at the top of the second column. I suspect this is because the `thead` somehow gets "repeated" on the column break as well as the page break:

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this?

I also only care about achieving this in the latest Chrome browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Cut "**page-footer**" div and paste it in the last of body and create the new div for table section like below

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="page-header" style="text-align: center">
    I'm The Header
    <br/>
    <button type="button" onClick="window.print()" style="background: pink">
      PRINT ME!
    </button>
</div>

<div>
        <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="page-header-space"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
         </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                 <div class='two-column'>
                  <div class='content'>1</div>
                  <div class='content'>2</div>
                  <div class='content'>3</div>
                  <div class='content'>4</div>
                  <div class='content'>5</div>
                  <div class='content'>6</div>
                  <div class='content'>7</div>
                  <div class='content'>8</div>
                  <div class='content'>9</div>
                  <div class='content'>10</div>
                  <div class='content'>11</div>
                  <div class='content'>12</div>
                  <div class='content'>13</div>
                  <div class='content'>14</div>
                  <div class='content'>15</div>
                  <div class='content'>16</div>
                  <div class='content'>17</div>
                  <div class='content'>18</div>
                  <div class='content'>19</div>
                  <div class='content'>20</div>
                  <div class='content'>21</div>
                  <div class='content'>22</div>
                  <div class='content'>23</div>
                  <div class='content'>24</div>
                  <div class='content'>25</div>
                  <div class='content'>26</div>
                  <div class='content'>27</div>
                  <div class='content'>28</div>
                  <div class='content'>29</div>
                  <div class='content'>30</div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>
                  <div class='content'></div>

                 </div>
              </td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>

          <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <!--place holder for the fixed-position footer-->
              <div class="page-footer-space"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
  </table>

  </div>

  <div class="page-footer">
  I'm The Footer
  </div>


</body>          
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Still has the space at the top of the second column.